# How to display the tag as content in HTML?

Tags: html

How to define this tag as content on my Html Page?

```
  <h1> <h1></h1>
```

.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
     <title><title></title>
     </head>

     <body>
      <h1> <h1></h1>

      <p> This is my first Paragraph</p>

     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: What? Was there a question attached to this post at some point?

Comment: I want to display the html tag as my content on page how can i achieve this for example my page looks like
<h1> is the content of my header on the page?

Comment: You know how to use tags - you've already done it in the example! `<p></p>` and `<body></body>`, therefore the same goes with every other HTML tag - `<h1></h1>`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean that you want "<h1>" to show as a heading?

You'll need to encode the text like so:

```
<h1>&lt;h1&gt;</h1>
```

There are a few converters you could use such as http://www.web2generators.com/html/entities

Comment: Yes i got it Thanks :) Few people don't get the question and vote down your question :(

Answer (score 2):

Base on my understanding, I think you want to display the < > directly.
You will need to encode your html.

For example, `<` to `&lt;`, `>` to `&gt`;

Here's an online tool for this:
http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/HTMLEncode/Encode.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple answer.

```
<h1> This is how to use this tag in an HTML site/application </h1>
```

When you open any HTML tag like this

```
<span>
```

You must also close it like this

```
</span>
```

Any children of that tag must be placed between the open and closing tags e.g.

```
<span><p> An example of parent/child tags in HTML </p></span>
```

**WAIT A MINUTE**

Do you just want to use `<h1>` as text for your header??

If thats what you want, p.s. you are not being clear here at all. then here

```
 <h1>   &lt;h1&gt;  </h1>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4yznscwb/)

Comment: <h1> This is my header<h1></h1> How can i display this information as header of my page??????

Answer (score 0):

what about `xmp` ?

```
<xmp style='padding:0px;margin:0px;white-space:nowrap'>
 <h1> This is my header<h1>
</xmp>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/r4w30jej/)